# Using "pandas.read_csv" such that all columns dtypes are "object"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to use `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv")` such that all columns in the `"Data_set_name.csv"` are of type object so that I don't have to convert each column type after?

For example, when I use `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv", dtype={'col_name': object})` the `'col_name'` will be of dtype object, however I would like this to be done on all columns instead of one in a line of code similar to this one.

Comment: Did you try: `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv", dtype='object')`? Note, if you have not conventional `NaN` values like `N/A` as a string, this method will not work. You have to specify them with `na_values` argument like: `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv", dtype='object', na_values='N/A')`

Comment: I might be wrong - but I am not sure that could be done - object is general when the dtype couldn't be picked up (let's say a mix of nans string and dates) - also let's say you ignore the dtype prediction even then everything would end up as string as it is a csv file. Why do you want everything to be an object?

Comment: Thank you @Erfan...I want everything to be an object so that I know that all columns are iterable.

Comment: Erfan's answer is bang on right and that's what you need I believe. I'll suggest Erfan to make it an answer, so that this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: @Kusi You mean so that all the column **values** are iterable, right? I mean, columns are always iterable. BTW, missing values aren't iterable, but I guess you don't have any missing values in your data set.

Answer (score 0):

Restating the answer [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56443905/#comment99481398_56443905) to close the loop. Thanks @[Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan)!

> Try `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv", dtype='object')`. Note, if you have not conventional NaN values like N/A as a string, this method will not work. You have to specify them with na_values argument like: `pandas.read_csv("Data_set_name.csv", dtype='object', na_values='N/A')`

This method worked for me.